# Which are the positivity conditions for sixth degree polynomials?

Tags: polynomials

I have a polynomial of degree $6$ with positive real roots. I need to know the conditions on its coefficients so that the polynomial is positive for any positive root, i.e.,

$$a_6x^6 + a_5x^5 + a_4x^4 + a_3x^3 + a_2x^2 + a_1x + a_0 > 0$$

and all $x_i > 0$

Ulrich and Watson found the conditions for quartic polynomials (SIAM J. Sci. Comput. 15, 3, 528-544, 1994). But, I don't find them for higher degree polynomials.

Comment: http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0915035

Comment: How can a polynomial be positive at one of its roots?